# Use Half-Normal to estimate Expected Loss

Tags: volatility, expected-value

Say a stock return follows a normal distribution with 0% mean and 50% volatility.  If I want to calculate the Expected Loss (ie. only the expected value of the negative returns), does it make sense to use Half-Normal Distribution's mean to approximate that value?

The Mean of a Half-Normal is sigma x sqrt( 2 / pi).  Does it mean the Expected Loss should be -50% x 0.8 = -40%?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the distribution of $X$ conditional on $X<0$, in particular for the conditional expectation

$$E[X|X<0].$$

For $X$ normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$, that turns out to be equal to

$$ E[X1_{X<0}]/P(X<0) = 2\sigma\int_{-\infty}^0 x \phi(x) dx $$
$$=2 \sigma \int_{-\infty}^0 -\phi’(x) dx  = -\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$$

Note that when the mean is $0$, half-normal and [one-sided truncated normal](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) distributions coincide. In particular, we have:

$$ |X|= X1_{X>0}-X1_{X<0},$$

leading to

$$E[|X|]=  \sigma/\sqrt{2\pi} +   \sigma/\sqrt{2\pi} =  \sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}. $$

Comment: Thanks.  Where does the 2 come from?  I see some derivation of a Half-normal by moving the left half to right half to keep total probability to be 1.  But if I am just trying to find the expected negative value by just integrating from -Infinity to 0 only of the left side of the normal distribution, would the expectation end up being different?

Comment: $P(X<0)= 1/2$ and $E[X1_{X<0}] =\sigma \int_{-\infty}^0 x \phi(x) dx = -\sigma/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for a CTE or TVaR value. Check out Wikipedia or the associated references for formulas.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_value_at_risk

http://uryasev.ams.stonybrook.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Norton2019_CVaR_bPOE.pdf

For the record though, you are probably underestimating your risk if you use a normal distribution. You should try using the Student T with ~4 degrees of freedom. This is more in line with empirical observation. See the introduction to the paper below:

https://www.uts.edu.au/sites/default/files/qfr-archive-02/QFR-rp194.pdf